# SQL, is a date within range of two dates

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have an SQL Server Database, managed through SQL Server MS, interfacing with a c# application and i am struggling with a certain query.

The database is for a campsite booking system, which consists of the following tables relevant to the query.

BOOKING(**BookingID**, StaffID, CustomerID, PitchID, StartDate, EndDate)

PITCH(**PitchID**, TypeOfPitch, Capacity)

One pitch can occur in many bookings.

I am looking to create a query which will check the availability of a pitch on a certain date, which is input from a dateTimePicker. The query will return the available pitches and display them in a datagridview. Here is what i have so far.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.PITCH, dbo.Booking 
WHERE @Date 
NOT BETWEEN dbo.BOOKING.[Start Date] AND dbo.BOOKING.[End Date]
```

This SQL code is not working, it is returning a pitch for every booking in the table.
All the c# around the SQL is working, i'm just not great at SQL queries and need some help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the SQL syntax should be `WHERE 
NOT @Date  BETWEEN dbo.BOOKING.[Start Date] AND dbo.BOOKING.[End Date]`.  This is the logic for `!(between)`.

Comment: @ryanyuyu `Not Between` is valid TSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.PITCH 
WHERE PitchID NOT IN 
(
    -- sub-query to take reserved pitches
    select PitchID from dbo.Booking 
    where @Date BETWEEN [Start Date] AND [End Date]
)
```

Comment: After Further testing, this is the query which worked, Returning all pitches that were not booked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want.  The sub query pulls the pitches that are booked during the given date.  So you want the pitches not in that query.

```
Select *
From dbo.PITCH
WHERE PitchID Not In (
    select PitchID 
    from dbo.Booking 
    where @Date between [Start Date] And [End Date])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SELECT 
,b.BookingID 
,b.StaffID 
,b.CustomerID
,b.PitchID 
,b.StartDate
,b.EndDate
,p.capacity

from Dbo.Pitch  p
INNER JOIN Booking b ON b.PitchID = p.PitchID
WHERE @Date  BETWEEN b.StartDate AND b.EndDate
ORDER BY @DATE DESC
```

Since you want the show the date picked from the PICKER at the top you need ORDER BY CLAUSE as well . 
Get in the habit of writing like this as it will help you easily solve as well as analyse the problem .
HOPE IT HELPS

Comment: You must declare the scalar Variable @DATE the query will throw an error

Comment: Unless you relate                                                                                    @Date = (some Table).DATE

Comment: AND NOT ( BETWEEN b.StartDate AND b.EndDate)